# Can you connect to two postgres databases in Springboot?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

If yes, how?

I am writing a archival project where old data from one database has to be moved to another. For this, I need to connect to two database in a springboot project.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide two different `DataSources` (two different beans).

Take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources